# Why does the formula for the angle between 2 lines give negative angles?

Tags: functions

[A Link to an image proving the angle between two lines formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxRCc.png)

So I've recently come across this formula in maths that allows you to find the angle between two lines. I understand the proof of the formula, it basically uses a trig identity (tan(x-y) = tan(x)-tan(y)/1+tan(x)tan(y)) and the fact that the angle of inclination of a line can be used to find the gradient of the line by using the tan function.

What I find confusing about the formula is that it can **have 2 forms** which can be:

[Form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6DQE.png)

[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd92B.png)

The form you get from the proof depends arbitrarily on which of the two lines you assign to be m1 or m2 as variables.

Apparently, when tan(θ) (where θ is the angle between the two lines) has a positive value, the angle you get from the formula will be acute.

But when tan(θ) is negative, the angle you get from the formula will be an obtuse angle. However, when you evaluate arctan(θ) with a calculator you get a negative angle when tan(θ) is negative.

Now usually people say this would make sense because if you think about the unit circle, when tan(θ) is positive it is in the first quadrant so you get an acute angle. When tan(θ) is negative, it is in the second quadrant so get an obtuse angle. What doesn't make sense to me is that tan(θ) can also positive in the third quadrant of the unit circle and is also negative in the fourth quadrant of the unit circle, which both give angles greater than 180°. An angle between 2 lines can never be greater than 180° or less than 0°.  So that argument as to why tan(θ) is sometimes negative when using that formula doesn't make sense to me.

I mean, without the definition of the unit circle which enables us to extend the trig functions to any angles (both negative and positive), how can this formula even work? How did mathematicians, who lived centuries ago (e.g. Pythagoras), know how to evaluate negative ratios in order to get an angle? Was the unit circle even defined back then? Did they even discover this formula in those times? Where trig functions even defined during those time periods?

These are all the questions that confuse me about this formula.

Another thing people also say is to just slap an absolute vale sign around the equation and therefore you will only get the positive value and an acute angle which makes sense and is not negative. But this also confuses me. Because why are we, out of nowhere, allowed to assign an absolute value sign to the equation, ignoring any negative values that could be obtained from the formula?

So the questions I am asking are, why does the formula sometimes give negative angles which makes no sense? What does the negative angle mean? And what if the unit circle definition of trig functions didn't exist, then how could you explain the negative ratios you can sometimes get from the formula?

Comment: Pleaase use MathJax to format equations and formulae. Link here- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the intersection of two lines, you will find four angles.  Two of them are identical acute angles, and two of them are identical obstuse angles (except in the case of perpendicular lines). The negative value is the tangent of the obtuse angle, and the positive value is the tangent of the acute angle.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103435/discussion-on-answer-by-omnomnomnom-why-does-the-formula-for-the-angle-between-2).